# Is this really a Klein Bottle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, klein-bottle

[image]

In an exercise it is asked to triangulate the Klein Bottle, and it is presented by this octagon. I really can't see a Klein Bottle here.

Comment: Have a peep here, http://mathsci2.appstate.edu/~sjg/class/1010/wc/geom/num7.html

Comment: Haven't taken Algebriac Topology, but is it perhaps obtained through aligning the edges according to arrow directions?

Comment: It's not even a surface, let alone a Klein bottle. Not with three-to-one identifications of the $b$ edges, and also of the $a$ edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lee Mosher points out, this fails to even be a surface. The reason is that a typical open neighborhood of a point in the interior of an "$a$" or "$b$" edge looks like three open half-disks glued together along their diameter. But this space cannot be homeomorphic to the plane. Indeed, removal of a point inside the common diameter yields a space homotopic to three intervals with corresponding endpoints identified, and this in turn is homotopic to a wedge of two circles. On the other hand, removing a point from inside the plane results in a space homotopic to a circle.